# Prevent user duplicating or adding new sheets to Excel manually

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in using Excel VBA. I have an Excel VBA code that will duplicate a certain sheet for n times. I want to prevent user from changing the workbook structure manually (such as adding new sheet, duplicating sheet, or moving sheet), but I still want the VBA to be able to run.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping you could use `UserInterfaceOnly` but that appears to be only worksheet level and not workbook level - it locks the worksheet for users, but allows VBA code to make updates.

The only other way I can think of is to lock and unlock the workbook as needed:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    UnlockWorkbook

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    LockWorkbook

End Sub

Sub LockWorkbook()
    ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="aaa", Structure:=True
End Sub

Sub UnlockWorkbook()
     ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="aaa"
End Sub
```